# Is it good to use SQL function like JSON_EXTRACT for large number of data

Tags: mysql, sql, database, oracle, database-performance

I'm implementing a DB, that is going to hit more than **2000** records per day and I'm going to fetch the data by using **SQL** Function such as **Mysql JSON_EXTRACT** and **ORACLE JSON_VALUE**. becarse. I'm storing data in JSON column.

I will use **Mysql JSON_EXTRACT** and **ORACLE JSON_VALUE**  functions for search a data range like below

```
SELECT *
FROM audit
where json_extract(detail_x,'$.eventDt') > '2017-10-01 00:00:00'
  And json_extract(detail,'$.eventDt')   < '2018-11-01 00:00:00'
```

Max date range will be **30days**. so,
Max row count will be around 2000 * 30 = **60000**.

My question is. is it fine to use **SQL** Function such as **Mysql JSON_EXTRACT** and **ORACLE JSON_VALUE** for this scenario.

Open to disuss.
Thanks.

Comment: I am *not sure* if MySQL is effectively indexing the JSON columns. If you are going to do searching on certain keys from the JSON; I think it would be better if you store those values separately in a different column, and also store them in JSON

Comment: Pls test and benchmark. Typically you want to perfrom the coarse filtering using relational functionality (index, partition), the fine access you can leave on JSON (to gain flexibility),

Comment: @MadhurBhaiya thank you very much for your feedback appriciate your idea. actually, design if the audit table can't change at the moment. so need to use JSON column and use the JSON_EXTRACT for MySQL and JSON_VALUE for ORACLE. do you hope it will be a bad performance issue?

Comment: @Dinesh at the end of the day, these functions are *like* string operations. So as the data scale up, they will definitely have performance issues; since indexing cannot be used, and a complete table scan would be done everytime, even if you are fetching data for 30 days only.

Comment: totally agree with you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you know that all rows have `eventDt`, then you should extract that into a column.  An index on the column will then speed many of your queries.  Admittedly, the index may not be useful for such a wide timespan, but it should improve performance when you are retrieving a small number of records.

The purpose of JSON should be to store data that has irregular formats that don't fit into columns.  MySQL doesn't index JSON directly.

You can always add an index using a generated column:

```
alter table audit
    add column eventDt date generated as (json_extract(detail_x,'$.eventDt')) stored;

create index idx_audit_eventDt on audit(eventDt);
```

Answer (score 1):

MySQL 8.0.21 introduced a new function `JSON_VALUE`:

> [JSON_VALUE(json_doc, path)](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/json-search-functions.html#function_json-value)
>
> Extracts a value from a JSON document at the path given in the specified document, and returns the extracted value, optionally converting it to a desired type.
>
> **JSON_VALUE() simplifies creating indexes on JSON columns by making it unnecessary in many cases to create a generated column and then an index on the generated column.** You can do this when creating a table t1 that has a JSON column by creating an index on an expression that uses JSON_VALUE() operating on that column (with a path that matches a value in that column)

In this case:

```
CREATE INDEX idx_t1 ON audit( (JSON_VALUE(detail, '$.eventDt' RETURNING DATE)) )
```

**[db<>fiddle demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=819afe256de3d762927b59fb729469e8)**